# MySql stored procedure call error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am getting the following error on calling a MySql stored procedure from phpMyAdmin

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I am using

```
call get_ledger_name(2007);
```

to call the procedure

I have tried changing password for root, creating a new user, but the error still prevails.

Comment: You need to ensure that (a) the username/password is correct and (b) that user has the necessary access to the database and tables.  But I would be VERY concerned at your network security if root and no password connects!

Comment: @Andrew : i have given all privileges

Comment: @NitinKabra are you sure that the username and password you have entered was correct?

Comment: OK, ta. Suggest you add (to the question) the EXACT command you're using

Comment: @JW. yes username and password is correct..

Comment: Check your username and password **mysql** database. Execute the query **select host,user,password from user**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter stored procedure with **DEFINER=root@localhost** and then call this SP. It will run.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_test`()
BEGIN
/* Your Code Snippet */
/* Your Code Snippet */
/* Your Code Snippet */
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You have changed password is good but for this issue there is no need to reset the password.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can reset the `root` password.

- [How to Reset the Root Password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html)

But keep in mind that it is *not advisable* to use `root` account without password.